# Display error messages in html

Tags: php, html, validation

I want to display warning messages in html. This code shows two text boxes named "company" and "name". `con.php` connects to the database and inserts the information. But if I enter nothing, then the values are still getting stored in the database as `null`. I want user to know that he shouldn't leave the fields blank by displaying some messages and also a warning should appear if the given company already exists in the database. How do I implement that?

```
  <html>
   <head>
 <title>store in a database</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
    <body>
   <h2>company  Store</h2>
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="con.php">
      <p>company:<input type="text" name="company">
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="40">
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>

          <input type="submit" value="Save">
          <input type="button" onclick="window.close()" value="cancel">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't do this with (pure) html; if JavaScript is an option then this is quite easy, or it could (and *should*) be checked server-side as well with whatever scripting language you're using to populate your database.

Comment: HTML 5 has some validation properties. But they are not really impelmented jet. Like David Thomas told, you must check the data on the server side too. @David Thomas: He is already using javascript, see the cancel button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is using `Ajax` if you want to do it at the same page. You need to read some tutorials on it. It's not that easy to explian here.

If reloading or redirecting to other page is ok for you, you should compare the submitted form value with the values in the database in a `PHP` script which is redirected from form submission (action url). If values doesn't match and not empty, store the values to database and redirect to a page like the list of companies or "company successfully created" message page. If values match with an old record or empty, redirect back to the same form page with a flag (something like `form.php?error=1` etc.) and show the proper error message.

Also you can use `JavaScript` for immediate alerts. But you should always do the same checks at `PHP` side since `JavaScript` can be disabled in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

While an alert message cannot be produced without JavaScript, you could take advantage of HTML5's `placeholder` attribute to inform the user of this message:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="You must enter something in this field"! name="whatever" id="whatever" />
```

And couple this with JavaScript:

```
var inputElem = document.getElementById('whatever');
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

form.onsubmit = function(){
    if (inputElem.value = '' || inputElem.value.length < 1){
        alert('You must enter some actual information');
        return false;
    }
};
```

However JavaScript can be edited by the users, via Firebug, Web Inspector, Dragonfly...or by simply creating a new html file and submitting the form to the same source from the `action` attribute of the `form` element. Therefore your form-handling script ***must*** be sanitised and checked on the server as well as the client; client-side checking is a convenience to the user (to prevent unnecessary page-reloads, submissions and so on), it is ***not*** a security feature, and should not be used, or mistaken, as such.

Answer (score 0):

In con.php you should do your data validation and return the markup (or redirect to page describing the error).

So, check for empty fields, and if the exists redirect the user to a page saying the fields can not be empty (and probably allow them to enter new values).

If the data entered is ok, check the database for duplicates and if they exist, redirect the user to a page saying that the company already exists (and again probably allow the user to correct the data).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it only with HTML.

You need to add a form validation (to prevent empty strings), HTML5 form validation can do that for you (check http://www.broken-links.com/2011/03/28/html5-form-validation/), but not all browser support it, so you will need to use JavaScript to validate the form.

There are JavaScript libraries that will take an old browser and make it behave like a browser that support HTML5 (check http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html).

You will also need to retrieve the companies already in your database and check them against the user input and alert him if needed.

On top of that you will need to validate the data in your PHP before inserting it to the database (check for empty string for example).